# Haskell, higher order functions and what input belongs here?

Tags: function, haskell, input

because I don't understand higher order functions in haskell, I tried this

```
tryout :: (a ->b) -> Int
tryout p q = 4
```

and I could also do
     tryout p = 4
why is it possible to do p as well as p q ?

```
tryout :: (a ->b) -> Int
tryout p q = 4
```

and when I was playing around trying to get it, I called tryout with 3 4, 3->4 and with 3 and it all didn't work. 
Could someone explain to me what I'm doing here, why p as well as p q can be written (that is probably because p = a->b and p en q is a and b) and could I get an example of what I could do to call tryout?

Comment: The above produces an error, `tryout` here takes *one* parameter. A function of type `a -> b`.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. But I still don't get what a -> b means. What is a function of a type a -> b? could you explain it to me real simple, because I feel like I am not grasping any concept of this.

Comment: By type signature, `tryout` takes only one function parameter with type (`a -> b`) and returns an `Int` type value. Such as `tryout f = const 4 f` or (`tryout = const 4` as a shorthand). It might as well use `f` to eventually produce an integer value instead of discarding it.

Comment: `a -> b` is the type of *any* function, because neither the input type nor the return type is restricted, and the two don't have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

`tryout` takes *any* function as its argument, and returns an integer. Because you don't have any value to call the function on, `tryout` can't do anything but ignore it, and return some integer. (There is one total implementation of `tryout` for each value of type `Int`.)

```
tryout :: (a -> b) -> Int
tryout _ = 4
-- tryout (+) == 4; (+) :: Num x => x -> x -> x, where a ~ x and b ~ x -> x
-- tryout return == 4; return :: Monad m => x -> m x, where a ~ x and b ~ m a
-- tryout length == 4; length :: Foldable t => t x -> Int, where a ~ t x and b ~ Int
-- etc
```

If `tryout` *also* took an additional argument to type `a`, you could at least apply the function to get a value of type `b`, but you still couldn't do anything with it, since `tryout` has to return an `Int`.

```
tryout :: (a -> b) -> a -> Int
tryout _ _ = 4

-- tryout length "foo" == 4; a ~ String, b ~ Int
```

Now, imagine that in addition to the function of type `a -> b`, the value of type `a`, you *also* had an argument of type `b -> Int`. *Now* we can finally do something non-trivial (though still simple).

```
tryout :: (a -> b) -> a -> (b -> Int) -> Int
tryout f x g = g (f x)
```

We apply `f` to `x` to get a value of type `b`, then pass that to `g` in order to get an `Int` we can return. It's not the *only* definition that type-checks; we can
still ignore `f`, `x`, and `g` and return a fixed `Int` as with the previous examples.